# 404 action after Struts upgrade to 2.5.30 from 2.2.1

Tags: java, xml, spring, jar, struts2

I upgraded from Struts 2.2.1 to 2.5.30 and made the following changes in lib

Upgrade the following jar files:

- freemarker-2.3.31.jar
- ognl-3.1.29.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.30.jar
- struts2-convention-plugin-2.5.30.jar
- struts2-core-2.5.30.jar
- struts2-json-plugin-2.5.30.jar
- struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.30.jar

---

Delete the following jar files

- org.apache.struts.xwork-xwork-core-2.2.1.jar
- org.apache.xwork-xwork-core-2.2.1.jar

---

Add the following jar files:

- commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar

---

And made the following changes in web.xml and Struts.xml
web.xml (before)

````
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>XXX</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filter -->
    <!-- Character Encoding filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Struts2 filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2CleanupFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Filter -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2CleanupFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--Spring ApplicationContext -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.imps.spring.listenner.ContextAwareListenner</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring  Introspector -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- session -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScheduleJob</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imps.util.schedulework.ScheduleJob</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>   
    
    <servlet>                           
        <servlet-name>CheckToken</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imps.util.CheckToken</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
                         
    <servlet-mapping>                   
        <servlet-name>CheckToken</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CheckToken.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>```

web.xml (after)

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>XXX</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filter -->
    <!-- Character Encoding filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Struts2 filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2CleanupFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Filter  -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2CleanupFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--Spring ApplicationContext -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.imps.spring.listenner.ContextAwareListenner</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring  Introspector -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- session -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScheduleJob</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imps.util.schedulework.ScheduleJob</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>   
    
    <servlet>                           
        <servlet-name>CheckToken</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imps.util.CheckToken</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
                         
    <servlet-mapping>                   
        <servlet-name>CheckToken</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CheckToken.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>```


struts.xml (before)

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="crud-default" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="servlet" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="com.imps" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10241024000" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="C:\test" />


    <!-- CRUD Action parent package -->
    <package name="crud-default" extends="convention-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="crudStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="crudStack" />
    </package>
    
    <package name="cbi-default" extends="json-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="com.imps.servlet.LoggingableJSONResult" default="true" />
            <result-type name="json-hierarchy" class="com.imps.servlet.HierarchySupportJSONResult" />
        </result-types>
    
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="errorHandler" class="com.imps.servlet.ErrorHandlerInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="authHandler" class="com.imps.servlet.AuthInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="cbiStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="errorHandler"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="authHandler"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="cbiStack"/>
    </package>
</struts>```

struts.xml (after)

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="crud-default" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="servlet" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="com.imps" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10241024000" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="C:\test" />


    <package name="projectstruts" extends="struts-default" strict-method-invocation="false">
        <global-allowed-methods>regex:.*</global-allowed-methods>
    </package>
    
    <!-- CRUD Action parent package -->
    <package name="crud-default" extends="convention-default" strict-method-invocation="false">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="crudStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="crudStack" />
    </package>
    
    <package name="cbi-default" extends="json-default" strict-method-invocation="false">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="com.imps.servlet.LoggingableJSONResult" default="true" />
            <result-type name="json-hierarchy" class="com.imps.servlet.HierarchySupportJSONResult" />
        </result-types>
    
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="errorHandler" class="com.imps.servlet.ErrorHandlerInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="authHandler" class="com.imps.servlet.AuthInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="cbiStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="errorHandler"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="authHandler"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="cbiStack"/>
    </package>

</struts>
````

But 404 occurred in the action after the modification, where did I modify the error, please provide me with suggestions.

Reference:

- https://blog.csdn.net/vifaceeeeee/article/details/124713625
- https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8ab7f42b71775d1ce8d4f1
- https://blog.csdn.net/leoluoxu/article/details/80448277

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You should be seeing some logging error messages--those are almost always the best place to start, and should be included in the question.

Comment: Finally, I recompiled all the files that use the 'action', and it can work.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces for filter-related classes have changed at 2.5.  Specifically, `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` is now `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+2.5.

Comment: Thank you but you may see my xml before modification.